# MPI_Group_excl fatal error when trying to exclude process rank 0. c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, runtime-error, mpi

Hello everyone i'm pretty new to coding in general and MPI.
    I'm sure this must be a pretty silly mistake but i can't understand why this code:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int arg, char** argvs) {
    int rank, numOfProcess;
    MPI_Init(&arg, &argvs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfProcess);

    int ranks[1] = { 0 };
    MPI_Group orig_group, new_group;
    MPI_Comm new_comm;
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &orig_group);
    MPI_Group_excl(orig_group, numOfProcess - 1, ranks, &new_group);
    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &new_comm);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

gives me the following error:

```
 $ mpiexec -n 3 Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects/MPImisc/Debug/MPImisc.exe

 job aborted:
 [ranks] message

 [0] fatal error
 Fatal error in MPI_Group_excl: Invalid rank, error stack:
 MPI_Group_excl(group=0x88000000, n=2, ranks=0x008FF800, 
 new_group=0x008FF7E8) failed
 Invalid rank in rank array at index 1; value is -858993460 but must be in 
 the range 0 to 2

 [1] fatal error
 Fatal error in MPI_Group_excl: Invalid rank, error stack:
 MPI_Group_excl(group=0x88000000, n=2, ranks=0x012FF860, 
 new_group=0x012FF848) failed
 Invalid rank in rank array at index 1; value is -858993460 but must be in 
 the range 0 to 2

[2] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Group_excl: Invalid rank, error stack:
MPI_Group_excl(group=0x88000000, n=2, ranks=0x012FFB10, 
new_group=0x012FFAF8) failed
Invalid rank in rank array at index 1; value is -858993460 but must be in 
the range 0 to 2

---- error analysis -----

[0-2] on ASUSPC
mpi has detected a fatal error and aborted Documents/Visual Studio 
2015/Projects/MPImisc/Debug/MPImisc.exe

---- error analysis -----
```

Correct me if i'm wrong but the "new_group" that i'm creating should contain every process but the one with rank 0.
Why is it giving me this error? i specified in the array "ranks" that i want to remove the rank 0, i'm lost.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

you did not use `MPI_Group_excl()` correctly.

> **SYNTAX**
>
> ```
>    int MPI_Group_excl(MPI_Group group, int n, const int ranks[],
>         MPI_Group *newgroup)
> ```
>
> **INPUT PARAMETERS**
>
> ```
>    n         Number of elements in array ranks (integer).
>
>    ranks     Array of integer ranks in group not to appear in newgroup.
> ```

since `ranks` is an array with one element, this is how you should update your call

```
MPI_Group_excl(orig_group, 1, ranks, &new_group);
```